# Check C program output in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Is it possible to do a platform check for the output of a program?

Let's say I want to compile this program:

```
#include <library.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << LIBRARY_MAGIC_VALUE << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and run it (within CMake configure step) to extract the value of `LIBRARY_MAGIC_VALUE`.

In the [How to write platform checks](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks) (moved to: [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Write-Platform-Checks)) guide it seems that this use-case is not contemplated, or specialized only to specific things (like checking the size of a type).

How can I implement such a check?

Comment: CMake 3.0 has a "execute_process" the deprecated version is "exec_program" I think. Instead of trying to cout you can do a return LIBRARY_MAGIC_VALUE and set the return variable in "execute_process" and use that value to do the check?

Comment: execute_process doesn't cover building the program right? if I add the program as a target, how do I specify that it is needed at configure step?

Comment: Correct, its more like running a secondary program to determine the values you are after. You could add it as a dependency. So VersionChecker first and then the AppUsingVersionChecker, each with its own CMakeList.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [try_run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/try_run.html) command for such checks:

```
try_run(LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_RUN_RESULT
    LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_COMPILE_RESULT
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/library_magic_val
    "test_library_magic_val.c"
    RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_OUTPUT)

# Do not forget to check 'LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_RUN_RESULT' and
# 'LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_COMPILE_RESULT' for successfullness.

# Variable LIBRARY_MAGIC_VAL_OUTPUT now contains output of your test program.
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Also note that to specify include path one has to use the `CMAKE_FLAGS` keyword such as `try_run(RUN_RESULT COMPILE_RESULT binary source.c CMAKE_FLAGS -DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=/path/to/foo RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTVAR)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the CMake built-in [`try_run`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_run.html) command as follows:

```
TRY_RUN(
    # Name of variable to store the run result (process exit status; number) in:
    test_run_result

    # Name of variable to store the compile result (TRUE or FALSE) in:
    test_compile_result

    # Binary directory:
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/

    # Source file to be compiled:
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cpp

    # Where to store the output produced during compilation:
    COMPILE_OUTPUT_VARIABLE test_compile_output

    # Where to store the output produced by running the compiled executable:
    RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE test_run_output)
```

This attempts to compile and run the given check in `test.cpp`. You still need to check whether `try_run` succeeded to compile and run the check, and handle the output appropriately. For example, you can do something like this:

```
# Did compilation succeed and process return 0 (success)?
IF("${test_compile_result}" AND ("${test_run_result}" EQUAL 0))
    # Strip whitespace (such as the trailing newline from std::endl)
    # from the produced output:
    STRING(STRIP "${test_run_output}" test_run_output)
ELSE()
    # Error on failure and print error message:
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Failed check!")
ENDIF()
```

Comment: Thanks, try_run is the way to go